Checking the Maximum Principle where state constraints are present but slack: can I drop them?
I have an optimal control problem with a control $u\in [a,b]$, a state $x(t)$ and the law of motion $x'(t)=f(t,u(t))$ for some smooth $f$. The control is chosen to maximize:
$$
\int_0^1 J[t,x(t),u(t)] dt,
$$
subject to the state constraint that for every $t\in [0,1]$, $c\leq x(t) \leq d$.
I want to verify that a certain pair $x^*,u^*$ is not the solution by showing it fails to satisfy the PMP. However, the PMP with state constraints is cumbersome. However, the above state constraint is slack for $x^*,u^*$. Can I then drop it and say that the solution must satisfy the PMP for the problem without the state constraint?

If the constraint is not active then perhaps the gradient of the cost is non zero at $u^*$?

Sorry, could you explain?

Suppose (by contradiction) your candidate $(x^\star, u^\star)$ is a local optimum for the constrained problem, but the constraints are not active (or slack as you say, where we agree that this means that the inequalities are satisfied strictly over the whole interval), it means that it is a local optimum also for the unconstrained problem. Can you see it? So it should satisfy the unconstrained PMP necessary condtions.

Yes that is clear to me, and this is exactly the reason why it seems to me you can drop them. I just wanted to make sure that the proof of the unconstrained PMP does not require me to be able to change the function also non locally, in a way these constraints (even though they are slack at $(u^,x^)$) would prohibit.

The idea is that if you consider a control $u$ close to $u^\star$, then the corresponding solution $x$ will be close to $x^\star$. So, for any $u$ ''close enough'' to $u^\star$ the corresponding solution $x$ will also satisfy the constraint. This argument can be made precise, with several notions of closedness (L^\infty with strong/weak$^\star$ convergence, $L^p$ with strong/weak convergence, etcetera) depending on your context and on the continuity properties of $f$ .
I suggest to check in classical books topics like ``convergence of solutions'' and continuous dependence from parameters''...

Makes sense, thank you!
